# restore failed-error coded=0x3ed (the volume does not contain a recognized file system drivers are loaded and that the volume is not corrputed)

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, acer-aspire, acer-aspire-one

I have an aspire z3101-u4062 that was donated to me.

the previous owner pirated movies and went on bad web sites

The computer most likely got a nasty virus.

I turn on screen it just flashes a small line on the top left and than goes black.

I ran linux mint via Cd drive and wasn't able to install it

it said that there was no media but i was able to run it live

so i tried downloading ubuntu and now ubuntu does a weird thing were it goes black

than i called shop by systems for the recovery discs

I ordered the recovery discs from shop by systems via Accer supplier etc.

I put the system disc in

It tells me to put the 1/3 recovery disc in

The computer than reads "restore failed-error code 0x3ed (the volume does not contain a recognized file system drivers are loaded and that the volume is not corrupted)

I called Microsoft but they suggested buying a OEM clean installation of windows 7 and than they also suggested that i pay 100.00 dollars for a year of tech support.

I called geek squad and they said that the recovery disc should be sufficient but maybe the hard disc is damaged because the recovery disc should be all that you'll need. They also said they'd look at it for 200.00 bucks with a free 15 minute consultation.

I actually took the computer in to a free geek donation store where they erased the entire hard drive and he suggested the same thing which was getting a clean installation of windows 7.

i am now sitting down....speechless as to what to do next with it.

should i buy windows 7 OEM clean installation?
should i just get a new hard drive?

or is my recovery discs supplied by accer enough to get it to work as a functioning computer as long as i gain more knowledge from someone?

should i just give up and toss it?

has anyone had this happen before?

is there a possible fix?

the computer specs are below

it came with windows 7 originally installed or at least i imagine.

the computer is five years old est.

```
windows 7 home premium 64-bit
21/.5 multimedia touch monitor  wih full hd 1080p
4gb ddr3memory
1tb hard drive
nvideia geforce 9200 graphics
multi-in-one media card rader
dvd-super multi drive
inegrated lan10/100/1000
```